# cordova.js:308 Uncaught TypeError: AppRate.preferences.openUrl is not a function at Function.AppRate.navigateToAppStore (AppRate.js:257)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

Please help me out with this issue.

Here is my `rateApp` function:

```
    rateApp() {
            this.appRate.preferences.storeAppURL = {
                android: 'market://details?id=com.notes.notesapp',
            }
            this.appRate.promptForRating(true);
        }
```

**Here is my plugins list:**

```
cordova-plugin-apprate 1.5.0 "AppRate"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.3.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.6.8 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 5.0.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using the spread operator inside the rateApp function.

```
rateApp() { 
  this.appRate.preferences = {
     ...this.appRate.preferences,
     storeAppURL: {
       ios: "XXXXXX",
       android: "market://details?id=com.xxxx.xxxx"
     }
     // Rest of custom properties here!
   }

   this.appRate.promptForRating(true);
}
```

Check following [issue](https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate/issues/263) in github for more info. I think you need to add the latest plugin, so
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apprate@latest`

Comment: can you send me complete function for ionic app click event

Comment: Hello @AthifShaffy Still i am facing same issue

Comment: I think its plugin related issue

Comment: Hello @ AthifShaffy ,I think plugins are deprecated, please check which one is that

Comment: @MahiReAnimate Updated answer :)

Comment: **i am aleady using latest pugin :** cordova-plugin-apprate 1.5.0 "AppRate"